What does the German establishment say about the sinking of the Maid of Kent? To what pilot does it attribute the sinking of the Lancastria?
The British have an official history of WWII.  Does Germany have something similar? Might Germany's WWII war diaries or something similar identify which Luftwaffe pilot or pilots were responsible for (a) the bombing of the Lancastria and the Maid of Kent and (b) the machine-gunning of those persons, military and civilian, who were on the Lancastria and in the water after the bombing?

The alleged machine-gunning, according to one author in a 2005 book.

I guess these type of documents (if they ever existed) might be in the USA or GB or Russia now.

Ref. Were RMS Lancastria survivors strafed?

Let's try to close the question (meaning bringing it closer to a yes / no answer, less "opinion based" -- not "voting to close" here). Are you asking whether the German opinion on these attacks is that they were legitimate (implying that you think they weren't)? Are you asking whether the pilot was prosecuted (implying that he should've)? What is it that you're actually asking?

I am not trying to be confrontational. I am trying to find out in what direction your interest lies. I.e. whether it's the legitimacy, the popular opinion at the time, the historic view, .... -- by keeping the question vague, answers are unlikely to be in-depth either.

Who, exactly, are the "German establishment"?

@JonCuster I will do you one better. When are the German establishment? ;-)

New user, posts one question reiterating a questionable narrative as "factually given", then does not return. Push question? Voting to close.

Germany has official archives like the Bundesarchiv. This does have significant surviving files of the Luftwaffe. Basic googling suggests that the Lancastria was sunk by II./KG 30. I don't know if their Kriegstagebuch is among the surviving documents.

The group commander of that formation was Hauptmann Claus Hinkelbein, decorated on June 19th 1940 for his engagements against the British Navy with the Knights's Cross of the Iron Cross.

@ccprog, on the one hand that sounds like a good fit, but were two days enough for the paperwork? I know that sometimes, lesser officers got lesser medals months after the fact. It he was decorated for the attack, you should write it up as an answer.

There is a semi-official German history Germany and the Second World War.

@o.m.: As this sublink to your "Luftwaffe" link explains, war diaries usually don't include information on individuals or their missions.

@DevSolar, my answer focusses on one sub-question of the main text, the existence of archives. A better one would talk about the ships, but I cannot provide that.
